# Typing effect for a single element

Tags: javascript

I want to create a typing effect but for only a single element like`<p>`, not for the entire body of the page, this code snippet works perfectly, but it creates the effect for the entire page, I don't know `Javascript`.

```
var str = document.body.innerHTML.toString();
var i = 0;
document.body.innerHTML = "";

setTimeout(function() {
    var se = setInterval(function() {
        i++;
        document.body.innerHTML = str.slice(0, i) + "|";
        if (i == str.length) {
            clearInterval(se);
            document.body.innerHTML = str;
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

Thanks for any help you could provide.

Comment: do you want to have a typewrtier effect? if so create a `span` tag and add the letters you have to that elements NOT to the body element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you made almost all the work, what you miss is that you have to select the element you want to modify :

1. create a `<p>` (or any other tag, there's no limit)
2. add an `id` to the tag
3. in your js select the tag with [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
4. replace every instance of `document.body` from your snippet to the selected element

I removed the `setTimeout` as it gived nothing imo, feel free to add it back if your situation needs it
I remplaced `var`s by `let`s as vars can sometime gives unexpected results on bigger scripts

```js
const element = document.getElementById("typed")

let str = element.innerHTML;
let i = 0;
element.innerHTML = "";


let se = setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    element.innerHTML = str.slice(0, i) + "|";
    if (i == str.length) {
        clearInterval(se);
        element.innerHTML = str;
    }
}, 100); 
// I slowed the interval to make it more visible it only type the center element
```

```html
text shown everytime
<p id="typed">
this text will be typed
</p>
this text shown everytime too
```

---

this second snippet allow you to have multiple typed message in the same page if needed

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("typed")

Array.from(elements).forEach(el => {
  let str = el.innerHTML;
  let i = 0;
  el.innerHTML = "";
  
  let se = setInterval(function() {
      i++;
      el.innerHTML = str.slice(0, i) + "|";
      if (i == str.length) {
          clearInterval(se);
          el.innerHTML = str;
      }
  }, 100);
})
```

```html
text shown everytime
<p class="typed">
this text will be typed
</p>
this text shown everytime too
<p class="typed">
this text will be typed too
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice well explained answer !

Answer (score 2):

First add *ID* attribute for elements which requires typing effect.

```js
var str = document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML.toString();
var i = 0;
document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "";

setTimeout(function() {
    var se = setInterval(function() {
        i++;
        document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = str.slice(0, i) + "|";
        if (i == str.length) {
            clearInterval(se);
            document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = str;
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>

Text without typing effect

<p id="heading">Text with typing effect</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need `getElementById` and two `span`s, and for making it a little bit real, an animation for simulating the cursor.

[Her is](https://k-five.github.io/red-cursor/) a more advanced code if you liked.

```js
let span = document.getElementById( 'typewriter')

const text = 'How are you today?';
const length = text.length;
span.innerText = '';
let index = 0;
let se = setInterval(function() {
    span.innerText = text.slice(0, index);
    if (index++ == text.length) {
        clearInterval(se);
        span.innerText = text.slice(0, index);
    }
}, 100);
```

```css
#cursor {
  white-space: pre;
  background-color: #f00;
  animation-name: cursor;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-play-state: running;
}
@keyframes cursor {
   0% {     opacity: 1; }
  50% {     opacity: 0; }
  100% {     opacity: 1; }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id='typewriter'></span>
  <span id='cursor'>_</span>
</body>
</html>
```